# Obtaining zero instead of Inf from Postgresql in R

Tags: r, postgresql, dbi

I am inserting a dataframe containing infinity to PostgreSQL, then when I make a query I obtain zero. What am I missing?

```
library(DBI)

conn <- dbConnect(drv = RPostgres::Postgres(),
                  dbname = "my_db",
                  host = "localhost",
                  user = "db_admin",
                  password = pw)

rm(pw)

mydf <- data.frame(column_1 = c("A", "B", "C"), column_2 = c(1, Inf, 3))

dbWriteTable(conn, "mytable", mydf, row.names = FALSE)

from_df <- dbReadTable(conn, "mytable")

from_df
```

The result obtained from db.

```
  column_1 column_2
1        A        1
2        B        0
3        C        3
```

When I check in the db I can see that it is Infinity.

**Edit 1:**

With the old driver;

```
library(RPostgreSQL)
conn_old <- dbConnect(drv = dbDriver("PostgreSQL"), 
                      dbname = "my_db",
                      host = "localhost",
                      user = "db_admin",
                      password = pw)

dbWriteTable(conn_old, "mytable_old", mydf, row.names = FALSE)

from_df_old <- dbReadTable(conn_old, "mytable_old")

from_df_old
```

I obtain the same wrong result.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 17763)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=French_France.1252  LC_CTYPE=French_France.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=French_France.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                  
[5] LC_TIME=French_France.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] RPostgreSQL_0.6-2 DBI_1.1.0        

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] bit_4.0.4       compiler_4.0.3  hms_0.5.3       tools_4.0.3    
 [5] Rcpp_1.0.5      bit64_4.0.5     vctrs_0.3.4     blob_1.2.1     
 [9] pkgconfig_2.0.3 rlang_0.4.8     RPostgres_1.2.1 fortunes_1.5-4
```

Comment: if you're stuck with using `RPostgres` package you can look to make explicit column types using `field.types` in `dbWriteTable()`. It seems `RPostgres` maps R `numeric` to pg `numeric` that doesn't support `Inf` values

Comment: @EJJ, when I look with pgAdmin, I can see that column_2 has an Infinity value.

Answer (score 3):

That would appear to be a bug in package `RPostgres`. The older `RPostgreSQL` handles it just fine:

```
R> drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
R> conn <- dbConnect(drv, dbname="my_local_db_name_here")
R> mydf <- data.frame(column_1 = c("A", "B", "C"), column_2 = c(1, Inf, 3))
R> mydf
  column_1 column_2
1        A        1
2        B      Inf
3        C        3
R> dbWriteTable(conn, "mytable", mydf, row.names = FALSE)
[1] TRUE
R> from_df <- dbReadTable(conn, "mytable")
R> from_df
  column_1 column_2
1        A        1
2        B      Inf
3        C        3
R>
```